# node.js mysql insert ER_PARSE ERROR near HANDLER RESOLVED

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, serverless-framework

I have an API running in AWS Lambda written on Node.JS (6.10.3), using the npm package mysql (2.13.0).  This is deployed and managed using Serverless.

I am Inserting a single row into a table on a MariaDB RDS instance using the following code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  "host": process.env.CONFIG_HOST,
  "user": process.env.CONFIG_WRITE_USER,
  "password": process.env.CONFIG_WRITE_PW,
  "database": process.env.CONFIG_DB,
  "connectionLimit": 1
});

module.exports.post = (event, context, callback) => {
  var body = JSON.parse(event.body);
  var params = event.someParameter;
  var sql = getSql(body.name);

  console.log(sql);
  connection.query(sql, onQueryComplete(params, callback));
}

const onQueryComplete = function(params, callback) {
  return function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      callback(null, 'some error response');
    }

    // do something else...
  }
}

function getSql(name) {
  return `
    INSERT INTO lds_config.test_table
    (
      name,
      name_hash
    )
    VALUES
    (
      '${name}',
      MD5('${name}')
    );`;
}
```

If I check the table, I can see that the insert has completed successfully and the new row has been added, however error is being set - meaning something has gone wrong somewhere (possibly after the insert).

The error returned by mysql (in console.log) is:

```
{
  Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'HANDLER RESOLVED _____');
   // Timeout clearing if needed
       ' at line 2
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (...\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket <<stack trace continues>>)
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0
}
```

This is followed by a second error, stating that callback is not a function:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
TypeError: Uncaught error: callback is not a function
```

Similar code is working elsewhere in the API for selects.  Thanks!

Further notes:
The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE lds_config.test_table(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(500), name_hash CHAR(32));
```

The result from `console.log(sql);` is:

```
INSERT INTO lds_config.test_table
(
  name,
  name_hash
)
VALUES
(
  'test01',
  MD5('test01')
);
```

Which works when I run it directly in mysql workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the query also since the first error is regarding MySQL syntax. About callback is not a function it is not passed as a parameter in below code as far as I see.

```
const onQueryComplete = function(params) {
  return function(error, result, callback) {
    if (error) {
     console.log(error);
     callback(null, 'some error response');
    }
    // do something else...
  }
}
```

Above is the corrected one.

Comment: Thanks - I missed that when copying the code across!  I do have the callback being passed to the onQueryComplete function, however it is in the  '=function(params, ...)' part.  I have amended my original query.

Comment: I have now edited my original post to add the sql code generating the issue.

Comment: Looks like ok, but I may advise looking at the Sequence.js:52:14, you can even debug it.

Comment: Found the issue - it was related to myself in a later stage not passing callback on, which was causing some issue in SLS-offline package logging an error into the mysql connection.  Solved it now :)

Thanks